# Установка tkinter python в окружение pyenv

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, pyenv

Пытаюсь установить tkinter в виртуальное окружение с версией python 3.6.2, но модуль устанавливается в python 3.8.2. Как это исправить. Ubuntu 20.04. Для создания виртуального окружения использую pyenv

```
Python 3.6.2 (default, Sep  9 2020, 14:01:46) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ylanaish/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

Comment: tkinter встроенный модуль, его устанавилвать не надо же

Comment: При импорте выдает ошибку

Comment: можешь приложить скриншот ошибки?

Comment: Да, сейчас приложу

Comment: Приложил текст,

Comment: Возможно это [ответ на твой вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459444/tkinter-python-may-not-be-configured-for-tk)